# Apex controller and Salesforce profile access controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

my scenario is that I had a lightning aura component which displays the name of the account.What I'm trying to achieve is if the user is System Admin, he can see the apex return account name. If the user is standard user, he will see the message: You don't have permission to access this. I have already disabled the apex class access from the Profile setting. But no luck, the standard user still can see the account name. Am I doing anything wrong?

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="testing">
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="apexgetAccNameResults" type="Account[]" />
    
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-small">
        <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.apexgetAccNameResults}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.apexgetAccNameResults}" var="item">
                <p>{!item.Name}</p>
            </aura:iteration>
            
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <p>
                    You don't have permission to access this.
                </p>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:renderIf>
                
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccName");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.apexgetAccNameResults", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class testing {
    
    public testing() {
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccName() {
        return [
            SELECT Name
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id = '0012w00000MrHjYAAV'
        ];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Define `System Admin`. Is it the profile name? or is it `customize Application` permission?

Comment: It is the Salesforce standard profile "System Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Update your code in Apex like so

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccName() {
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        if (users.size() != 1) {
            throw new SecurityException('You do not have required access');
        }

        return [
            SELECT Name
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id = '0012w00000MrHjYAAV'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was trying to avoid this kind of control as this is hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: Ahm, you have very specific requirements, how else do you want to maintain them? this is exactly why I asked what defines a 'System Administrator'.